# bytearray from a webcam

Tags: actionscript-3

i try to get a bytearray from a webcam. i can get the image of the webcam, copy it to bitmapdata and get the bytearray. but is it possible to get the bytearray from the image and sound from the client's webcam ?

Comment: This is very confusing. I understood the bit where you use BitmapData's draw() and getPixels() methods, so that is possible. What I didn't understand is how you would get sound from a webCAM ? Do you not get sound from the Microphone ? Could you rephrase your question please ?

Comment: i want to get a bytearray of all the data (sound & image) from a webcam. i have webcam on stage, with sound. i would like to send all bytearray data from the camera to a server.

Answer (score 2):

audio data to ByteArray:

 * [Microphone.sampleData Event](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Microphone.html#event:sampleData)

 * [SoundMixer.computeSpectrum() method](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/SoundMixer.html#computeSpectrum%28%29)

i know only the following way to get a ByteArray from Video instance:

 * to draw a BitmapData each time the screen is updated and then [`BitmapData.getPixels(new Rectangle(0, 0, BitmapData.width, BitmapData.height))`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#getPixels%28%29)

it's also possible to join ByteArrays with video and audio data but it depends on how it'll be treated on the server side

Answer (score 0):

if i had the rep, i'd thumbs up www0z0k's reply... should help me with my own app.

Mel, however you're planning on processing the ByteArray on the server (i'd assume something with NetConnection.send()), i'd be sure to ByteArray.inflate()/ByteArray.deflate() your data transfer.

Comment: Moreover, if you created an AIR app on the server to process the sent data, you could also NativeProcess against something like ffmpeg or mencoder to compile an array of images/sound into a video output of your choosing.